# Nginx routing issue with angular 4

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

Can someone solve Nginx routing issue
my conf file has the following location section

```
  location /pages {
     alias /path/to/dist/folder
     index index.html;
   }
```

when I am hitting http://example.com/pages, I am getting http:example.com/pages/home page as per angular 4 routing, but when I directly hit http:example.com/pages/home -its throwing bad request 502

Answer (score 2):

Try the following redirection of routes to the `index.html`

```
index index.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: It will redirect each and every request to the `index.html` page, then how can I know for which page the user has requested originally?

Comment: The path stays the same, it's just what is served that will always be the `index.html`. That way any routing you defined in your app will pick up and handle what the user wanted to navigate to.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332924/angular-5-routing-issue