# Angular 5 routing issue

Tags: javascript, routes, angular5

I am using Angular 5 for my frontend application and Java for the server side stuff. I have an issue with Angular routing.

My problem is:

When a user enters this URL `http://example.net/public/public-data` in his browser URL bar and hits enter he gets `404`. Because of this requested resource is not available on the server so to deal with this problem I have written `.htaccess` the file which redirects each and every request to the `index.html` page.

After this change, the `404` problem is solved but one new problem I am facing,

> The new problem is: When a user hits
>   `http://example.net/public/public-data` he gets redirected to
>   `index.html` page, now I don't know which page he has requested
>   originally.

How can I know the original URL?

**EDIT**

Here is the code of my `.htaccess` file

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

**NOTE**

I am using subfolders, for example, `http://example.net/public/public-data` here public is my subfolder in which my Angular app code is placed. And `http://example.net` contains some `.php` files which do not have any connection with my Angular app.

Comment: Can you share your .htaccess file? Alternatively, you can make use of <base href="/" /> tag in <head> to set your base path

Comment: @Neeraj I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that .htaccess code and make use of `<base href="/public/">`

Your .htaccess will always check for the path other than index.html and redirect to it.

**index.html**

```
<head>
<base href="/public/">
<!-- Rest of your code here -->
</head>
```